# Android brute-force into an EditText

Tags: android, security, brute-force

Is it possible to brute-force into an editText of another application?

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    et1.setText( Integer.toString(i) );

    //1. et1 --> Perform DONE action
    //2. Wait for 5 sec
    //3. If this activity is still running retry with a different i-value
         //3. else; end.
}
```

Comment: Outside of the accessibility APIs, you have no access to widgets in other applications, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Is there a hacky way, where I can simulate an onTouch event at a specific point on the screen >> once the keyboard pops up, simulate the text being typed and entered? Maybe create a service that does this?

Comment: Then how does one brute force? Thought I'd stumbled upon a bug, was planning on collecting a bounty. The app lets you enter as many passwords as possible, no limit. Any way I can automate this?

Comment: "Then how does one brute force?" -- generally, you don't, and particularly not from an Android app. "Any way I can automate this?" -- use the UiAutomator testing tools, from your development machine, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You shouldn't ***Ever*** try to mess with other app's inner workings (EditText etc.) Only use such methods on your own apps or services.

You will get rejected by Google Play if your app tries to take control or content from other apps in this way.

In other words: Its not good practice to break into other apps that are not your own.

If they're your own, save the data you want to obtain in a file and have the other app read it.